# wallet.ethereum.org default tx fee is 1.05 ETH

Tags: wallets

[image]

This is the default tx fee set on wallet.ethereum.org, and the lowest I can drag the slider (why is this a slider? why can't I input the amount?) is 0.05 ETH which is currently around $40.

What's going on here?

Comment: are you sure you're on the mainnet. my recommended is `0.001113` and the slider reduces to as low as `0.000053`

Comment: Yes, I am on main net. I think I figured out the bug: I didn't have a valid receiving address in the input box. Not sure why that would cause this type of estimation to go wrong, but it's probably an edge case that hasn't been tested. I'll file a bug report, the issue was resolved on my end